# implement Double Word CAS by assambly

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to implement Double Word CAS by using `cmpxchg16b` in Linux g++ 4.4.6 X86_64,
unfortunately I am  not familiar with assembly code, after I googled many websites,
and implemented test source these days, it seems to work!  But I have no idea the 
following 2 assembly sources which will do better job. Any suggestions and comments are 
greatly appreciated!

```
struct ptr_
{
    uint64_t pointer;
    uint64_t serial;
} __attribute__ (( __aligned__( 16 ) )) ;
typedef struct ptr_ nodeptr ;
```

Source 1 :

```
inline static bool
cas_64_2(nodeptr *original,nodeptr *expected,nodeptr *newone)
{
    uint64_t *target ;
    uint64_t *compare;
    uint64_t *set ;

    target = (uint64_t *) original ;
    compare = (uint64_t *) expected ;
    set = (uint64_t *) newone ;
    bool z;

    __asm__ __volatile__("movq 0(%4), %%rax;"
                         "movq 8(%4), %%rdx;"
                         "lock;" "cmpxchg16b %0; setz %1"
                            : "+m" (*target),
                              "=q" (z)
                            : "b"  (set[0]),
                              "c"  (set[1]),
                              "q"  (compare)
                            : "memory", "cc", "%rax", "%rdx");


    return z;
}
```

Source 2 :

```
inline static bool
cas_64_2(nodeptr *original,nodeptr *expected,nodeptr *newone)
{
    uint64_t *target ;
    uint64_t *compare;
    uint64_t *set ;

    target = (uint64_t *) original ;
    compare = (uint64_t *) expected ;
    set = (uint64_t *) newone ;
    bool z;


    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "lock cmpxchg16b %1\n\t"
        "setz %0\n"
        : "=q" (z)
        ,"+m" ( *target )
        : "a" ( expected->pointer ), "d" (expected->serial )
        ,"b" ( newone->pointer ), "c" ( newone->serial )
        : "cc"
    );

    return z;
}
```

I have noticed that almost sources found in the websites implement like source2  ,
There is only one website I found implement like source1 , my g++ compiler is too old ,
so using `__uint128_t`  is not an option.

Comment: Where did you get these?

Comment: Offhand the second one looks better because it's correctly using input constraints for the inline asm rather than unnecessary movs and clobbers.

Comment: @potatoswatter  , from http://www.financecomputing.net/wordpress/?p=263 and http://blog.lse.epita.fr/articles/42-implementing-generic-double-word-compare-and-swap-.html , and a lot while google cmpxchg16b

Comment: It looks like you are using gcc or derivatives? Then you should definitively use the atomic builtin that this compiler provides, e.g `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt ,__sync_val_compare_and_swap is not for me in this version of g++ , since I won't be able to use __uint128_t datatype ,so compile by using gcc -mcx16 only work in newer compiler,thanks for kind advice !